# Is it possible to locally run multiple apps that run on different node versions at the same time?

Tags: node.js

Example:

I have a web app that runs v6.3.1 node and an api that runs v0.10.40
If I run both the web app and api under one version, one of the apps would break.

If I am developing both apps locally at the same time, I need my environment to be able to run both apps locally each using a different version of node. Is there any tool(s) that would help me do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should install `nvm` for managing all the versions of node you need.

After you install `nvm` you can get all the node versions you need and then you can open different terminals and choose the version you want for each app using `nvm use v6.3.1` or `nvm use v0.10.40`.

GitHub for `nvm` can be found here: https://github.com/creationix/nvm/blob/master/README.markdown